# Kotlin coroutine list returning null value

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

New at development of android apps. I am using kotlin and I am triying to retrieve a list from room database at my viewmodel and make a toast at my fragment when I push a button (codes below). If I push the button once, I get an empty string, but if I push twice, I get the list. How can I do to retrive the list with just one push? Probably I am missing something from coroutines.

Viewmodel code:

```
var Listado = ""


    fun listaTotal(): String {
        uiScope.launch {
            getTodaListaCompra().forEach{
                Log.i("Listado Compra",Listado )
                Listado = Listado + " " + it
                Log.i("Data",data.value)
                Log.i("Pueba",it)
            }
        }
        return Listado 
    }
```

Fragment call:

```
Toast.makeText(application, tabListaCompraViewModel.listaTotal(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining an empty string at start. When listaTotal() gets called the first time, a coroutine gets launched in background to calculate the value of 'listado'. However the return of listaTotal is not waiting for the background coroutine to finish. That's why 'listado' is still empty.

Between your first and second click on the Button, the first coroutine finishes and  'listado' now is not empty anymore, so when you click the button the second time, the coroutine gets launched again but 'listado', again gets returned before that coroutine finishes, so it returns the result of the first button click.

Because you can only make a Toast on the main UI thread, you need to tell it to wait for the coroutine to finish to get the returned value. You can do it using runBlocking, like this:

```
fun listaTotal(): String = runBlocking {
    getTodaListaCompra().forEach{
        Log.i("Listado Compra",listado )
        listado += " " + it
        Log.i("Data",data.value)
        Log.i("Pueba",it)
    }
    listado
}
```

Update:
To clarify, this approach blocks the main UI thread until the result is returned. 
You should therefore consider using LiveData (see Sergeys answer) or Flows for fetching data. The purpose of this answer is mainly to explain the behavior of your code and coroutines in general.

Comment: @enriqueanaemmagarciacardenas My guess is this is not what you are expecting. `runBlocking` is blocking current main thread https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html. The same effect you can achieve without using coroutines at all. If calling `getTodaListaCompra()` takes much time your UI will freeze. You can check this inserting calling`delay(5000)` function right before calling `getTodaListaCompra()`.

Comment: Hi @Sergey, sure, I can achieve same effect with dealy(5000) but if I call getTodaListaCompra() without coroutine, I get a force close cause I can block main thread.

Comment: Hi @enriqueanaemmagarciacardenas, using `runBlocking` you are also blocking main thread as you can see by the docs: `Runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread interruptibly until its completion`. You can experiment a little bit: make function `private suspend fun getTodaListaCompra(): List<String> {
        delay(10000) // simulate request delay
        return listOf("one", "two", "three")
    }`
And you will see that your main thread is blocked. Using `LiveData`, `suspend` function and `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` you will not block the main thread.

Comment: @Sergey: You are right about blocking, I would  suggest using LiveData as well, or even better, Flows. But the question was, how he can retrieve the list, so this answer is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using **LivaData** to observe data:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val listado: LiveData<String> = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun listaTotal() = viewModelScope.launch {
        var localListado = ""
        getTodaListaCompra().forEach{
            localListado = "$localListado $it"
        }
        (listado as MutableLiveData).value = localListado
    }

    // function marked as suspend to suspend a coroutine without blocking the Main Thread
    private suspend fun getTodaListaCompra(): List<String> {
        delay(1000) // simulate request delay
        return listOf("one", "two", "three")
    }
}
```

In your activity or fragment you can use next methods to instantiate **ViewModel** class and observe data:

```
private fun initViewModel() {
    val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this,
            viewModelFactory { MyViewModel() }
    )[MyViewModel::class.java]

    viewModel.listado.observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { data: String ->
        Toast.makeText(application, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    })

    viewModel.listaTotal()
}

inline fun <VM : ViewModel> viewModelFactory(crossinline f: () -> VM) = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(aClass: Class<T>):T = f() as T
}
```

Also you may need to import next libraries:

```
api 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$LIFECYCLE_VERSION'
```

Comment: Thank you for this approach. I found really interesting and I will try after setting everything up.